# Sifting through binary data on Linux?

Tags: linux, search, binary

I have a directory in which I want to look for any copy of the number "512245"
There are several files of multiple types, so I can't search them directly

What's the easiest way to analyze the binary of all these files looking for this number?
That'd be "1111101000011110101"

Answer (score 1):

*od* and *grep* could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can pipe the output of hexdump to `grep`